# how do I get the current user's birth-day and phone number using facebook sdk in android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, sdk

I am using a facebook sdk in android

I need current user's phone_number and birthday and I don't know what to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> and also provide some help on how to get api key from facebook. i have
>   only app_id at this point.

Hi, getting the secret key (aka API key) for your app_id is really simple:

Simple go to the URL: https://developers.facebook.com/apps/{Your App ID Here}/summary 
and it is listed as **App Secret:** in the top box of the Settings page.

Comment: "secret key (aka API key)" that's pretty confusing since there was an API key until only recently. And the rule of thumb is: You can use the App ID (!) where previously an API key was required. DON'T USE THE APP SECRET SOMEWHERE WHERE THE API KEY WAS/IS REQUIRED! Otherwise you may be creating huge security holes.

Comment: @ jan Olaf Krems : thanks for help. i will take care of it. can you tell me how to get current user's date of birth and phone_number from the sdk m little bit confuse about it..

Comment: Mahaveer, please ask this new question in a new question, you'll get more visibility for it. Hint, play around with the graph API explorer tool.  If you can get it figured out from playing there, please ask a new question.  :)